# Is mspec better with or without nunit?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, nunit, mspec

I've seen mspec used with nunit on some blogs and discussions. In fact, most of the examples on the web that I've seen demonstrate mspec with some kind of nunit dependancy or integration. My team is attempting to use mspec without nunit on a new ASP.NET MVC2 project. We're not at the spec-writing stage yet, so I can't tell what is better. What it your experience with this? Are there benefits to using mspec with nunit? Without?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

MSpec does not depend in any way on NUnit or xUnit. As such you can use MSpec on its own, as it has it's own runners and assertion methods. The blog posts you saw very likely used the "old" assertion library that were dependent on either NUnit or xUnit. This dependency has been removed in late 2009.

What you can do, although it's neither required nor do I see any benefit in doing it, is to use NUnit's assertion library (`Assert.IsTrue` et al.) together with MSpec.

Answer (score -3):

since you not have started yet, take a look at SpecFlow, it integrates nicely with MSTest and Visual Studio....

Comment: MSpec has integration with Visual Studio through ReSharper or TestDriven.NET.

Comment: -1 because it answers a different question than the one asked